# Find the dictionary from List which has key-pair 'isGeo':True

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dictionary

How to Find the dictionary from List which has key-pair 'isGeo':True

```
dimensions = [{'key': 2600330, 'id': 'location', 'name': 'Location', 'isGeo': True, 'geoType': 'region'}, {'key': 2600340, 'id': 'subject', 'name': 'Subject', 'isGeo': False, 'geoType': None}, {'key': 2600350, 'id': 'measure', 'name': 'Measure', 'isGeo': False, 'geoType': None}]
```

I want to below result:

```
{'key': 2600330, 'id': 'location', 'name': 'Location', 'isGeo': True, 'geoType': 'region'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) with a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
res = next((d for d in dimensions if d['isGeo']), None)

{'key': 2600330, 'id': 'location', 'name': 'Location', 'isGeo': True, 'geoType': 'region'}
```

Since you tagged [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), you can also use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dimensions)
res = df.loc[df['isGeo']].iloc[0].to_dict()
```

The above solutions assume you want only the *first* dictionary satisfying your condition. If you want a list of dictionaries use:

```
res = [d for d in dimensions if d['isGeo']]
res = df.loc[df['isGeo']].to_dict('records')
```

Comment: another doubt if list "dimensions" has multiple dictionary d['isGeo'] == True, I think next will give one list, how to get multiple results

Comment: Got it  - [dimension for dimension in dimensions if dimension['isGeo'] == True] will give multiple dictionaries

Answer (score 1):

Another way is [`list comprehension`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)

```
dimensions = [{'key': 2600330, 'id': 'location', 'name': 'Location', 'isGeo': True, 'geoType': 'region'}, {'key': 2600340, 'id': 'subject', 'name': 'Subject', 'isGeo': False, 'geoType': None}, {'key': 2600350, 'id': 'measure', 'name': 'Measure', 'isGeo': False, 'geoType': None}]

geoDimension = [dimension for dimension in dimensions if dimension['isGeo']][0]
```

Output : `{'key': 2600330, 'id': 'location', 'name': 'Location', 'isGeo': True, 'geoType': 'region'}`